# Excluding results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Course (one table) and module (another table).  Modules can be part of different courses. Joined in this table called coursemodule

```
CourseCode  ModuleID
       BS   BS2029
       CN   CN5485
       CS   CN5485
       BS   CS1004
       CN   CS1004
       CS   CS1004
       CS   CS2017
       BS   CS2026
       CS   CS2026
```

I want to select the modules that appear in both the CS and CN courses but not ones that also appear in the BS course.  If I run this:

```
SELECT m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDescription
FROM Module as m
INNER JOIN (SELECT coursecode, ModuleID 
            FROM CourseModule      
            WHERE CourseCode = 'CS') AS CodeCS
ON m.ModuleID = CodeCS.ModuleID            
INNER JOIN (SELECT coursecode, ModuleID 
            FROM CourseModule      
            WHERE CourseCode = 'CN') AS CodeCN
ON m.ModuleID = CodeCN.ModuleID
```

I get:

```
ModuleID        ModuleDescription
CN5485          Managing Networks
CS1004          Introduction to Programming
```

which based on this query is correct but I only want to return CN5485 as CS1004 is also in the BS course.

Tried not in, <>, except variations all with terrible success!  What do I need to be adding? amending in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query - it's easy to read and uderstand:

```
SELECT m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDescription
FROM Module as m
WHERE m.ModuleID in 
((SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'CN'
INTERSECT
SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'CB')
EXCEPT
SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'BS')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with something a little different - since you want two "in" and one "not in", I'd write it that way, which would make it clear what you're doing:

```
SELECT m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDescription
FROM Module as m
WHERE m.ModuleID in (SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'CS')
AND m.ModuleID in (SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'CN')
AND m.ModuleID not in (SELECT ModuleID FROM CourseModule WHERE CourseCode = 'BS')
```

The `in` syntax in my opinion is a little clearer than joining - joining to me implies that you want something from that table, when in fact you just want to make sure a match exists, not retrieve anything from it. Also joins can get you in trouble with duplicates if you're not careful - `in` won't.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of would be to use 3 queries. The first query will return all modules that have CS courses, then `Intersect` with a query that selects all modules that have CN courses. Take the result of the `Interact` and then run an `Except` against Moudles that are in BS courses.

So a simplified version of the query would look like this:

```
<Query to pull distinct Modules that have a CS course>
Intersect
<Query to pull distinct Modules that have a CN course>
Except
<Query to pull distinct Modules that have a BS course>
```

**Updated** query for Seetal's comment

```
Select ModuleId, ModuleName
From Module
Where ModuleID IN (
  <Query to pull distinct ModuleID that have a CS course>
  Intersect
  <Query to pull distinct ModuleID that have a CN course>
  Except
  <Query to pull distinct ModuleID that have a BS course>
)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help.  I've just realised I probably haven't made myself 100% clear as I also also need to show the module description which is in the module table.  Brian Ball, your answer seems very straightforward but I need to pull this description in too.

Comment: My solution is still good. You would just have those 3 queries be a sub query and they would just return the ModuleId, then use those subqueries in the where clause of the outer, query. This is the solution also proposed by @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Well don't know what version of SQL Server you are using. Try following (`except`) clause if your version supports this:

```
SELECT m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDescription
FROM Module as m
INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON (m.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID 
               AND cm.CourseCode IN ('CS', 'CN'))
EXCEPT --
SELECT m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDescription
FROM Module as m
INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON (m.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID 
               AND cm.CourseCode IN ('BS'))
```

You can try seleting `ModuleID`s and then descriptions.